# Do Russian speakers in the former USSR countries use patronymics?

Tags: узус, выбор-имени

Can the general calling conventions in Russian (for example - *Dimitri Ivanovich Petrov* will be formally referred to as *Dimitri Ivanovich*) be extended to the countries of the former Soviet Union  (particularly **Ukraine** and **Armenia**) ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please clarify what exactly do you mean by "extended to the countries"? Are you asking if it is OK to use patronymics in Ukraine and Armenia, or is the usage pattern the same, or what? Thanks!

Comment: I ask if the usage pattern is same or not in the former Soviet Union (Armenia, Ukraine, Georgia etc.) as it is in Russia.

Comment: In Ukraine, the patronimic is officially written in everybody's passport and all the other documents, too. However, in Ukraine in formal situations only the Ukrainian language is to be used, and in Ukrainian there are other traditional formal ways of address beside name+patronimic. But that's a story for [a different SE](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/), not this one.

Comment: Oh, I was asking in general for former USSR countries in general. Thought that should correspond to the common tying thread that is Russia in this case instead of three or four different forums for Ukraine, Armenia etc.

Comment: This stackexchange is about the Russian language, not about countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russian-speaking Ukrainians and Armenians, when communicating in Russian, do expect patronymics used towards them in the same way Russians do, and mostly they do have a preference about rendition of their patronymic in Russian.

For instance, Armenian prime minister Nikol Pashinyan [insists](https://ru.armeniasputnik.am/politics/20190125/16947076/Pashinyan-obyasnil-kak-pravilno-proiznosit-ego-otchestvo.html) that his patronymic is rendered *Воваевич* in Russian, because his father's given name is rendered in Russian as *Вова*.

Etymologically, *Вова* is a hypocorism (pet form) of Russian name *Владимир*, that's why some Russian speakers call him *Никол Владимирович*, which he deems wrong.

Forming the patronymic following the usual Russian pattern for names in *-а, -я* (*Фома > Фомич, Илья > Ильич* etc.) would give *Вович*, but he does not prefer this form either.